# How to Serialize-Deserialize the fingerprint of DigitalPersona u.ere.u 4500 in C# and saved to a database

Tags: c#, mysql, fingerprint

can you help me?
I want to save a fingerprint on mysql, this is the code I use.

```
private void enrollment_OnEnroll(DPCtlUruNet.EnrollmentControl enrollmentControl, DataResult<Fmd> result, int fingerPosition)
    {
        if (enrollmentControl.Reader != null)
        {
            ShowMessage("OnEnroll:  " + enrollmentControl.Reader.Description.Name + ", finger " + fingerPosition);
        }
        else
        {
            ShowMessage("OnEnroll:  lector no conectado, finger " + fingerPosition);
        }

        if (result != null && result.Data != null)
        {
            //valor de la huella serializada

            string valores = Fmd.SerializeXml(result.Data);
            MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection(_sender.cadena);
            String sql = String.Format("insert into cliente (clave_cuenta, huella) values('{0}','{1}')", textBox1.Text, valores );
            MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(sql, conexion);         
            try {
                conexion.Open();
                comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conexion.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("La huella se guardo satisfactoriamente","Almacenada",buttons:MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
            conexion.Close();
            _sender.Fmds.Add(fingerPosition, result.Data);                

        }

        btnCancel.Enabled = false;

       // _sender.btnApruebaCompra.Enabled = true;
    }
```

this is stored in mysql

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Fid><Bytes>Rk1SACAyMAAA8gAz/v8AAAFlAYgAxADEAQAAAFYjQIEAZmBkQIEARl5kQMoBKE1jgM8BA0RhgMwAg0tcgNYAZKZcQIIBFB5bgOYA00FaQM8BQFVZQKAAtV9YgLUBEVFYgGUApXNWQOQBIkRUQL0A00RUgPoAckxTQLQAeKVTgG4AcwRTQQMAoKFSQMsA5ptQgMsA65tQQFAAk2xQQREAq0dQgHkA0RhOQEYAoxdCgI8A7Hg/gOEBP00+QFUA4B48gEoAwnQ6QJkA3aA2gJwBAXU2AQMA7UE1AJ0BE2szAQgA7EEuAJwBDqwtAQ4AY6MqAAA=</Bytes><Format>1769473</Format><Version>1.0.0</Version></Fid>
```

It is supposed FMDs, but I can not return it to its original form.

as return to its normal shape?

Comment: String HuellaRecuperadabd = datos.Tables["cliente"].Rows[0]["huella"].ToString();
                Fmd.DeserializeXml(HuellaRecuperadabd);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string x = Fmd.SerializeXml(fmd);
```

store x in database as string.

retrieve the string and pass in

`Fmd val = Fmd.DeserializeXml`(retrieved string from database);

use **val** to compare to your current input.

Answer (score 0):

In my case using `Fmd.DeserializeXml()` gave me this error

```
    '\' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '"' or '''. Line 1, position 15
```

so i used the following for serialisation and deserialisation respectively

```
     Fid.SerialiseXml(CaptureResult.data);

     Fid.DeserializeXml(xml string retrieved from db);
```